# How to evaluate json member using variable ?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Hi i've got a problem evaluating json. My goal is to insert json member value to a function variable, take a look at this

```
function func_load_session(svar){

var id = '';

$.getJSON('data/session.php?load='+svar, function(json){

  eval('id = json.'+svar);

});

return id;
```

}

this code i load session from php file that i've store beforehand. i store that session variable using dynamic var.

```
<?php
/*
* format ?var=[nama_var]&val=[nilai_nama_var]
*/ 

$var = $_GET['var'];
$val = $_GET['val'];
$load = $_GET['load'];

session_start();

if($var){
  $_SESSION["$var"] = $val;
  echo "Store SESSION[\"$var\"] = '".$_SESSION["$var"]."'";
}else if($load){
  echo $_SESSION["$load"];  
}
?>
```

using firebug, i get expected response but i also received error

```
> uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: )
```

pointing at this

```
> eval('id = json.'+svar);
```

I wonder how to solve this

Answer (score 3):

The correct code to use is:

```
id = json[svar];
```

You may also want to add `alert(svar);` to check that `svar` contains the correct value beforehand.

However, your code still won't work: the `func_load_session` function will return immediately, before the ajax call finishes and before the `id` variable is assigned.

what you need to do instead is to perform whatever you want to do with `id` from the ajax callback function:

```
function func_load_session(svar){
    $.getJSON('data/session.php?load='+svar, function(json){
        var id = json[svar];
        doSomethingWith(id);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also If I understand and have full part of your code Your json comes out like Store["var"]="var" ??
Does not appear valid json

I suggest using php function json_encode()

So php would be

```
 $var = $_GET['var'];
$val = $_GET['val'];
$load = $_GET['load'];

session_start();

if($var){
  $_SESSION["$var"] = $val;
  echo json_encode(array($var=>$_SESSION[$var])); // or something like that 
}else if($load){
  echo json_encode(array('load'=>$_SESSION["$load"]);  
}
?>
```